# Nested JSONPath location as variable in JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json

I have been building a radio player that will pull metadata from various playlist APIs based on the station I'm listening to. Each of these APIs is structures a little different, so I'm trying to pass the JSONPath from a JS Object and use that to inform the data I pull from JSON.parse.

```
const stations = {
  radioStation1: {
    artist: "artist",
    song: "title",
    album: "album",
    image: "albumImageLarge",
    stationName: "radioStation1",
    streamUrl: "https://somestreamingurl",
    apiUrl: "https://streamingurlapi",
  },
  radioStation2: {
    artist: "results[0].artist",
    song: "results[0].song",
    album: "results[0].album",
    image: "results[0].image_uri",
    stationName: "radioStation2",
    streamUrl: "https://somestreamingurl",
    apiUrl: "https://streamingurlapi",
  },
};
```

Then in my code I assign the JS Object value to a variable and am able to reference it to pull the value from the API of radioStation1, because it's not a nested JSON response. So it would reference `data.artist` and return a result.

```
var stationName = "radioStation1";
var songPath = stations[stationName].song;

var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
console.log('songPath', data[songPath]);
```

Where the problem I'm running into is with radioStation2. Since to reference the same data from that second API I need to reference `data.results[0].song` the variable approach no longer works, since the variable doesn't seem to want periods or anything else, just the key name and not a full JSONPath. I've looked up and down for a solution on SO and beyond and most point to use using [] to use a variable, but I haven't seen anything pertaining to passing more complex JSONPath references. Is this even possible? Is there some better way to do what I'm trying to achieve?